# How to install Errbot in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, errbot

I'm trying to deploy Errbot in App Engine. Errbot needs the data directory to be writable but an App Engine instance's local filesystem is not writable. Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

From **[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/)**:

> **You are correct, GAE local filesystem that your application is deployed to is not writeable. This behavior ensures the security and scalability of your application.**

However, if your use case involves to store data in a persistent manner, you may consider using **[Cloud Storage to read and write files during runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/using-cloud-storage)**. App Engine creates a default bucket when you create an application.

This bucket provides the first 5GB of storage for free and includes a free quota for Cloud Storage I/O operations. You can create other Cloud Storage buckets, but only the default bucket includes the first 5GB of storage for free.